# Active model serializers - custom adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers

I would like to refactor an existing rails API using active model serializers.

Unfortunately the existing API uses a slightly different JSON schema than any of the the existing adapters and I have been unable to recreate it using AMS.

The schema I am trying to recreate is like this:

```
{
  "status": 0,
  "message": "OK",
  "timestamp": 1438940571,
  "data": {
    "contacts": [
      {
        "contact": {
          "id": "1",
          "first_name": "Kung Foo",
          "last_name": "Panda",
          "created_at": "2015-07-23T14:09:20.850Z",
          "modified_at": "2015-08-04T15:21:36.639Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "contact": {
          "id": "2",
          "first_name": "Johnny",
          "last_name": "Bravo",
          "created_at": "2015-07-23T14:09:20.850Z",
          "modified_at": "2015-08-04T15:21:36.639Z"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am wondering is there a way to create a custom adapter for active model serializers, or otherwise create this schema.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? `data` hash?

Comment: yes, the problem is with the data hash - answer below gives me 
`data: { contacts: [ {id:1, firstname: ..}, {id:2, firstname: ..}]}`
I need an extra contact root key for each contact object

Comment: Well, I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Could just use a couple of serializers.

```
class MessageSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :status, :message, :timestamp, :data
  # We could've just used that, were it not for nested hashes
  # has_many :contacts, key: :data

  attributes :data

  def data
    ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(object.contacts, root: 'contacts')
  end
end

class ContactSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :first_name, :last_name, :created_at, :modified_at

  def root
    'contact'
  end
end
```

There seems to be no better way to do that

Then somewhere in your controller:

```
render json: Message.serializer.new(@message, root: false)
```

Comment: hm, adding the root method in the contact serializer hasn't changed anything for me. I'm using verion 0.8.0 of the gem - is that likely to matter?

Comment: Yes, I'm on `0.9.3` and it seems to work. Though it could depend on other factors – I just played with it in `rake console`, and behavior could be different when executing from `render` call. Try to update and say if it doesn't work on new version as well – I'll revert my answer to more direct version of building hash.